# Problems with text editors on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, ruby, text-editor

So, I am new to Ubuntu, which is required for my CS course that primarily focus on ruby and Ocaml. The problem that I'm having is that whenever I try to open up the project file with command "ruby file.rb" or "Ocaml file.ml", it just prompts me to the next command line. I've also installed vscode on Ubuntu, and it turned out to be the same result, currently, the only text editor that I could use is emacs.

[ruby command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6mM5.png)

[Ocaml command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEcDg.png)

[vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpXlc.png)

Comment: `ruby` is not an editor - it is an interpreter that accepts the commands in "file.rb" and executes those commands.  Use Emacs to create your file, then execute it with `ruby filename"

Comment: fyi:  If you're not sure, you could `man ruby` which would tell you ruby is an *Interpreted object-oriented scripting language* along with giving you the reference page info on how to use it...  As a CS student this should be your first step (*not guessing like an end-user!*)